# at which points the function is differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Could anyone help me how to find those points in which $f(x,y)={x^3y\over x^4+y^2}; (x,y)\ne (0,0)$ is differentiable? 
is there any general formuale for calculationg directional derivative of $f$?

thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it's differentiable everywhere where $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$. To see that one simply calculate partial derivates and realize that these are continuous everywhere except at $(0,0)$ - because the partial derivate is a polynomial divided by the denominator squared (as per the formula for derivate of a ratio).

The formula for directional derivate is $f'_v = \nabla f\cdot v$ where $\nabla f$ is the gradient (and $v$ is a vector of unit length). The gradient in turn is $\nabla f = (f'_x, f'_y)$ **if** $f$ is differentiable. If on the other hand $f$ is not differentiable there's no such general formula.

Comment: Continuity of partial derivatives is a sufficient condition for differentiability, but not necessary, so this doesn't show anything for $(x,y)=(0,0)$. To show that $f$ is not differentiable there, check the definition directly instead. Like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3500295/fx-y-fracx3yx4-y2-is-not-differentiable-at-0-0

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes, but I think that point is explicitly excluded in the question (as the function isn't defined at origin as opposed to the function in the linked question).

Comment: Ah, you're right, of course. Sorry.